# Why vim's <Leader> key not working when I want to use bufexplorer or vim-buffergator plugin?

Tags: vim, plugins, vundle

I am using Ubuntu now.

I used `vundle` installed `bufexplorer` and `vim-buffergator` plugin for vim. But when I type `¥be` or `¥b`, the `<Leader>` key `¥` not working in the vim editor. Is it necessary to set something in the `~/.vimrc` file?

I didn't meet this problem until now, even I used Ubuntu or CentOS before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out whether the mappings have actually been defined via:

```
:verbose nmap <Leader>b
```

This will also show what key the `<Leader>` key is configured to. If there's no output, check whether the plugin has been correctly installed (output of `:scriptnames` lists the plugin script, commands like `:BufExplorer` are available, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much. When I typed `:verbose nmap <Leader>b`, it showed: `n  \bv         & :BufExplorerVerticalSplit<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/bufexplorer/plugin/bufexplorer.vim
n  \bs         & :BufExplorerHorizontalSplit<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/bufexplorer/plugin/bufexplorer.vim
n  \bt         & :ToggleBufExplorer<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/bufexplorer/plugin/bufexplorer.vim
n  \be         & :BufExplorer<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/bufexplorer/plugin/bufexplorer.vim` It looks good, maybe other problem?

Comment: Yes, that looks good, and your Leader key is ``\``. Do you press that?

Comment: Yes. Outside the vim editor, I can press that key(`¥`) and can see it worked well. How can you press it like "\"? Mine is "¥". Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Hm, strange. Do other mappings work (e.g. `:nnoremap ,, :version<CR>`)? Does it work when you trigger it via `:normal \be`?

Comment: I have found the reason! Now I am using the Mac OS. My <Leader> key is `¥` but not `\`! I changed a input method and resolved it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah great! Yes, input methods do complicate matters.

Answer (score 0):

`vim-buffergator` explanation mentioned conflict with `bufexplorer`.

From https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-buffergator :

[NOTE: If you have other plugins installed that have key maps that start with "<Leader>b" (e.g., BufExplorer, which uses "<Leader>bs", "<Leader>bv", etc.), then you may notice a slight delay or lag when typing the default "<Leader>b" to start Buffergator. In this case, you should either use another keymap for Buffergator or BufExplorer.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But at first, I didn't use the `vim-buffergator`, only the `bufexplorer`, the result was the same.